# Making a switch statement on my partials angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I'm having a problem, i'm unable to get my ng-switch to work on my partials. What I'm trying to do is upload an image but before I upload it I must first check if the included image size doesn't reach 25kb.

Here is my controller code:

```
$scope.validateAvatar = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    $scope.filesize = files[0].size;
    $scope.filemaxsize = 25;
//Take the first selected file
fd.append("file", files[0]);

    $scope.uploadAvatar = function() {
        Api.uploadAvatar($scope.main.user.email, fd)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result.data);
        }, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
    };
};
```

and my partials code:

```
<form data-ng-submit="uploadAvatar()">
    <input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().validateAvatar(this.files)"/>

    <div ng-switch on="filesize / 1024 < filemaxsize">
        <div ng-switch-when="true">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Avatar">
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
            Please choose you avatar.
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Also do you think my validation is enough when checking for the image file size, say what if the image included is size:20MB, will my validation still catch it? Sorry in the first place I haven't been able to make it work the switch statements first . :(

Comment: Instead of `onchange` you should use `ng-change="validateAvatar(this.files)"`

Comment: Also in your code the functions are nested. Move `uploadAvatar` out of `validateAvatar`.

Comment: @Codezilla, when i change from onchange to ng-change gave me an eror. Error: No controller: ngModel <input type="file" name="file" ng-change="validateAvatar(this.files)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` after you changed `$scope.filesize` manually.

BTW, why not just let `$scope.filemaxsize = 25 * 1024;`

Comment: oh, okay its working now. This is my first time using $apply. The docs in angularjs is scary to read. @_@. Also by making $scope.filemaxsize = 25 * 1024 then my partials expression would just be filesize <= filemaxsize. Is this correct?

Comment: @WonderingCoder: Yes.

Comment: this is weird, it's working when I refresh the page just for testing. but originally my app flows like this, when login -> profile and from profile page that where I upload the avatar. I had to click the choose a file button twice for the upload button to appear. Why is it like that?

Comment: @WonderingCoder: is `$scope.filemaxsize` only defined here? I think this should be in top level. Perhaps you insert `$scope.$apply()` between `$scope.filesize` and `$scope.filesize`?

Comment: oh yeah! its working now. woah, thanks a many men! BTW, this is out of the topic. Since I'm building a SPA web, refreshes in between pages are not allowed, right? But how do you handle if the user refreshes page? You get what I mean right?